# Adding a id,content in a bit complicated array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I want to update an array that has inside an object. I can't figure how I'm doing it in a smart way.I will get at the beginning (id, content) and the completed by default is false
(it's a dummy DB ) for example (6,test6) of course that's the number in byIds need to be the same"6"

```js
const DUMMY_PLACES = [
  {
    todos: {
      allIds: [1, 2, 3, 4],
      byIds: {
        "1": {
          content: "test1",
          completed: false,
        },
        "2": {
          content: "test2",
          completed: false,
        },
        "3": {
          content: "test3\\",
          completed: false,
        },
        "4": {
          content: "test4",
          completed: false,
        },
      },
    },
    visibilityFilter: "all",
  },
];
```

Comment: I need also help to delete one.

Comment: You say you want to update an array of objects, but the code shown has one array of numbers and an object with key value pairs (which also seems unnecessarily complicated for what you are doing). Also please show your attempt at solving the problem yourself

Comment: its because its a long term view when ill have listed of differents todo.Im trying to push in todo.allIds without succeeding, and do something similar in the ByIds

Comment: `DUMMY_PLACES.todos.allIds.push(6)` should work, please provide a [mcve]  as it's unclear where your problem is

Comment: I have to go but I will sure look at it and send you the minimal reproducible example, sorry for being such a noob... thanks for your help I will continue to test later

Comment: todo = DUMMY_PLACES;
    console.log(todo.todos); If i try to log it I get undefined

Comment: but if I do the same and I log the only todo(console.log(todo) I get the DUMMY_PLACES

Comment: Right, I misread your definition, it should be `todo[0].todos` - but you still haven't provided a [mcve] including your own attempts and the actual problem, so this question is off-topic

Comment: Thanks, I understood next time I will provide a reproducible example.